# Geoserver 2.13+ GetCapabilities is Missing XML Encoding

Tags: geoserver, wmts, getcapabilities

Hoping someone can help me on this.

So I've installed Geoserver 2.11 and am able to produce proper XMLs from my GetCapabilities.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Capabilities version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0">
```

This works fine for me inside my ArcGIS runtime.

But when I use version 2.13+ it is missing the XML encoding at the header of the GetCapabilities which is no longer recognized by my ArcGIS runtime.
I have tweaked every setting I could think of but cannot find a solution to this.
This is what my GetCapabilities looks like in the newer versions of 2.13+.
Notice there is no XML encoding, so my ArcGIS runtime does not recognize it as a valid XML. Does anyone have any suggestions? I have lost hours on this seemingly silly thing.

```
<Capabilities xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd" version="1.0.0"><ows:ServiceIdentification><ows:Title>GeoServer Web Map Tile Service</ows:Title>
```

Comment: Hmm... I just tried on a 2.15.x and the header is there, also quickly checked the code, the line that generates the header is there and has not been modified since 2014. Are you sure there is nothing else going on (proxies and the like) removing the header?

Comment: Hi Andrea. I appreciate you looking at this. Can't imagine it is. I installed 2.14 originally and it didn't work. I would get the GetCapabilities with no xml encoding. Went back down to 2.11 and boom it popped right up. I tried every single setting and config I could think of. Also tried 2.13 and same thing no Xml header.

Comment: Hi Andrea,
Here is a screenshot of how it looks for me. I just installed 2.14 on my local desktop, fresh installation and tried it. https://imgur.com/a/uI7q2GD You can see what I mean. If I do the same thing with 2.11 it will actually prompt me to download a proper XML.

Comment: What you have there is just the browser formatted version of the XML, check its source to confirm.

Comment: I just downloaded a 2.14.0 and checked, the formatted version states there is no stylesheet to display the XML (which has nothing to do with the xml declaration being present or not), and "show source" shows the xml declaration right at the top of the file.
You are assuming the XML declaration is to blame, but did you check there is nothing else that's different? Does ArcGIS provide any log as to what it thinks is not valid?

Comment: I tried everything I could find. I matched both my 2.11 and 2.14 installations to the letter on every single setting and nothing.I did get a response from ArcGIS but it didn't help. Will post another comment with it

Comment: We recently identified a few compatibility problems between Runtime 100.1+ and GeoServer 2.13+. We are working to fix these in future Runtime releases. Some of the issues can be worked around, for instance:
If no keywords are specified for the service, GeoServer/GeoWebCache inserts an empty `<Keywords />` element into the ServiceIdentification section of its GetCapabilities response.This currently causes Runtime to fail loading the rest of the service metadata. Workaround: You can avoid this problem by specifying at least one keyword for the service (and not just for the individual layers).